# Re-projecting Multiple Shapefiles using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, shapefile, coordinate-system, error-999999

I decided to re-project shapefiles from one coordinate system to another. I wrote the following script but am getting the execution Error 999999.

Here is the script:

[image]

```
import arcpy

# input data is in NAD 1983 UTM Zone 11N coordinate system
Input_Elk_Feature = "C:\Temp\Data\Originals\Elk\ds945.shp"
Input_ElkHuntZones_Feature = "C:\Temp\Data\Originals\Elk\ds786.shp"

# output data
Output_Elk_Feature = "C:\Temp\Projected_Data"
Output_ElkHuntZones_Feature = "C:\Temp\Projected_Data"


# create a spatial reference object for the output coordinate system
Out_coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 UTM Zone 10 North')

# run the tool
arcpy.Project_management(input_features, output_feature_class, out_coordinate_system) #reprojects the data into the specified coordinate system.

TestList = ["C:\Temp\Data\Originals\Elk\ds945.shp", "C:\Temp\Data\Originals\Elk\ds786.shp"]

x=0

while x>=0:
    Input_Elk_Feature = TestList[0]
    Output_Elk_Feature = "C:\Temp\Projected_Data"+0+".shp"
    arcpy.Project_management(input_features, output_feature_class, out_coordinate_system)

    x=x+1

    Input_ElkHuntZones_Feature = TestList[1]
    Output_ElkHuntZones_Feature = "C:\Temp\Projected_Data"+1+".shp"
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please provide your code snippet and the error message that results from it as text rather than a picture so that it is available for searching and testing, and is easy to view on any device.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted text nicely.

Comment: In python all your paths should be prefixed with an `r` - `r"C:\Temp\Data"` or use double slash `"C:\\Temp\\Data"` to avoid errors with python trying to use your folder names

Comment: Also I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the `while` loop at the end, but it will never exit that loop as `x` is always equal to or greater than `0`.

Answer (score 1):

The clue is in the error message:

```
e "U:\GSP318\Project\Reproject.py", line 13, in <module>
Out_coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 UTM Zone 10 North')
```

Your script is failing on the line setting the Spatial Reference.  At a guess it is the word `North` - usually these are written more like `NAD 1983 UTM Zone 10N`.  A quick test confirms it for me:

```
>>> sr = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 UTM Zone 10 North')
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.5\arcpy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 992, in __init__
    self._arc_object.createFromFile(item, vcs)
RuntimeError: ERROR 999999: Error executing function.
>>> sr = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 UTM Zone 10N')
>>> print sr.name
NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_10N
>>>
```

Change line 13 to be

```
Out_coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference('NAD 1983 UTM Zone 10N')
```

and your script should proceed past this line.

FYI I usually try to determine the SR projection code and use that when I set a Spatial Reference variable:

```
Out_coordinate_system = arcpy.SpatialReference(26910)
```

Esri provide a PDF in the ArcGIS folder (mine is located at `C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.5\Documentation\projected_coordinate_systems.pdf`) with coordinate systems that includes the codes, or you can get them from [SpatialReference.org](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/26910/)